# Is there programming way to implement revesion control in php website

Tags: php, version-control

I have website build in php .

I like the revision control system used in SO edited answers. like we can see al the old revisions.

Now i am new to that and have no idea how to implement it . i mean its a software plugin or its programmed like that.

If i want to do that on my all php files how to do that.

I know there are software for that  but how link those with website like SO has done . i mean although in the software there may be all the old versions but how to link those with webiste php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires more work with the database. Your application will have to store old revisions itself (or use triggers/views). Commonly a separate archive table is created for everything you normally store in your database. The crucial part of that is a version field:

```
CREATE TABLE articles (     // always the current version
     title VARCHAR,
     content TEXT
)
CREATE TABLE articles_ARCHIVE (
     version INT with AUTO_INCREMENT,
     title VARCHAR,
     content TEXT,
)    // yes, that's not a correct CREATE TABLE, just figuratively
```

And whenever you regularily would just update the articles table, you will instead first store the current version into the `_archive` table. And only afterwards store the new current text into the regular table.

Now to replicate what SO provides, you will also need some more UI logic. But a diff view for comparing _archive texts against the current version is not difficult (see [PEAR Text_Diff](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Diff)).

I think you could look into a [common Wiki](http://www.wikimatrix.org/) implementation to get an idea how it is done in practice.

Comment: so u mean , it was all programming , SO don't use software for that

Comment: There is no generic software for that. There might be database schemas (postgres), but SO does implement all by itself.

Answer (score -1):

Use [GIT](http://git-scm.com/) for your code control, and have a look at these [existing PHP frontends](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Interfaces,_frontends,_and_tools#git-php) to GIT to get you started.

SO's review system is custom-built I guess, so you'll have to build what you want on your own.